# Connecting to Cloudera HDFS in java code, getting UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera

So I'm trying to write code that can connect to an HDFS on a Cloudera (CDH 4.4) cluster running on an Amazon EC2 instance. I have all the ports I need to open, and I can access my cluster in pretty much every other way (web UI, ssh, etc) except in my code. Anytime I do, I get this:

```
15:07:35.115 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.m.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
15:07:35.125 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.m.lib.MutableMetricsFactory - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], about=, type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
15:07:35.127 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.m.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
15:07:35.605 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.s.a.util.KerberosName - Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
15:07:35.651 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups -  Creating new Groups object
15:07:35.654 [main] DEBUG o.a.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
15:07:35.654 [main] DEBUG o.a.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initUGI(UserGroupInformation.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)
    at org.skye.hadoop.stores.HdfsArchiveStore.initialize(HdfsArchiveStore.java:44)
    at org.skye.hadoop.HdfsArchiveStoreTest.testHdfsConfig(HdfsArchiveStoreTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:129)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:38)
    ... 45 more
```

Basically I can't find anywhere that can even explain where to start looking for what's causing this error. Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

"15:07:35.654 [main] DEBUG o.a.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library
"

Maybe the native library you loaded is incorrect. Check them in your "java.library.path".